# Set visibility on single tab in tabcontrol (winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, tabcontrol

Is there a way to set the visibility of a single tab in a tabcontrol?  I thought something simple like this should work, but does not seem to to anything.

```
tabControl1.TabPages[1].Visible = false;  
tabControl1.Refresh();
```

There will be a main tab that always shows but I want to have other tabs that I can "turn on\off".  I don't want to remove the tabs since I may need to show then again.

fk

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552579/how-to-hide-tabpage-from-tabcontrol (as per Philip's response below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Times haven't changed since 2.0:

[StackOverflow - How to hide TabPage from TabControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552579/how-to-hide-tabpage-from-tabcontrol)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `tabControl` page

```
this.tControl1.TabPages.Remove(this.tControl1.TabPages["tabPageName"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's obviously not part of the standard Windows Forms library, but the [Infragistics UltraTabControl](http://www.infragistics.com/support/documentation.aspx#OnlineDocumentation) has (among other features) a Visible property for each tab page.