# Hiding and Showing TabPages in tabControl

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol, tabpage

I am trying to show or hide tabpages as per user choice. If user selects gender male then form for male in a tabpage "male" should be displayed and if user selects female then similar next form should be displayed in next tab "female"

I tried using

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(...)
```

and

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(...)
```

It adds and removes the tabpages but doing so will loose my controls on tabpages too... i can't see them back. what's the problem here?

Comment: Is Visible property not working for tab pages?

Comment: Just verified: The Visible property is not actually exposed by Tab Pages.

Comment: And neither are the Show and Hide methods...

Comment: To hide all the tabs use tabControl1.Visible = false;

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You could remove the tab page from the TabControl.TabPages collection and store it in a list.  For example:

```
    private List<TabPage> hiddenPages = new List<TabPage>();

    private void EnablePage(TabPage page, bool enable) {
        if (enable) {
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(page);
            hiddenPages.Remove(page);
        }
        else {
            tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(page);
            hiddenPages.Add(page);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e) {
        foreach (var page in hiddenPages) page.Dispose();
        base.OnFormClosed(e);
    }
```

Comment: i am finding difficult to add the tab page... can u post some full eg. i understood your method but wonder how to refrence a tab while adding as it has been previously removed

Comment: Just add a member to your class.  The Windows Forms designer already does that, like "tabPage1".

Comment: liek to refer tabpage1 do i need to write me.TabPages("tabPage1") or what?

Comment: No, just use tabPage1.  It is a member of the form class.

Comment: hye it worked even wthout the hiddenpages variable... so any special use of it?

Comment: Yes, important to get the hidden page disposed when the form closes.

Answer (score 49):

I think the answer is much easier.

To hide the tab you just can use the way you already tried or adressing the TabPage itself.

```
TabControl1.TabPages.Remove(TabPage1) 'Could be male
TabControl1.TabPages.Remove(TabPage2) 'Could be female
```

a.s.o.

Removing the TabPage does not destroy it and the controls on it.
To show the corresponding tab again just use the following code

```
TabControl1.TabPages.Insert(0, TabPage1) 'Show male
TabControl1.TabPages.Insert(1, TabPage2) 'Show female
```

Answer (score 7):

Improving on the good solution by Hans Passant I decided to write an extension method based on his solution and adding other stuff as well. I am surprised that even in .NET 4 this basic functionality hasn't been fixed.

- Implemented it as an Extension Method that can be reused in a more transparent manner
- The clean up method only cleans up the pages of the control being disposed/cleaned up.
- Whenever possible the tab page is restored to its same position. This isn't always 
  possible if you hide/show several tab pages.
- It does some error and parameter checking
- To make it invisible it finds out its parent. When making visible it has to be given
  because the Parent property is null when the tab page has been removed.

```
public static class TabPageExtensions
{
        private struct TabPageData
        {
            internal int Index;
            internal TabControl Parent;
            internal TabPage Page;

            internal TabPageData(int index, TabControl parent, TabPage page)
            {
                Index = index;
                Parent = parent;
                Page = page;
            }

            internal static string GetKey(TabControl tabCtrl, TabPage tabPage)
            {
                string key = "";
                if (tabCtrl != null && tabPage != null)
                {
                    key = String.Format("{0}:{1}", tabCtrl.Name, tabPage.Name);
                }
                return key;
            }
        }

        private static Dictionary<string, TabPageData> hiddenPages = new Dictionary<string, TabPageData>();

        public static void SetVisible(this TabPage page, TabControl parent)
        {
            if (parent != null && !parent.IsDisposed)
            {
                TabPageData tpinfo;

                string key = TabPageData.GetKey(parent, page);
                if (hiddenPages.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    tpinfo = hiddenPages[key];
                    if (tpinfo.Index < parent.TabPages.Count)
                        parent.TabPages.Insert(tpinfo.Index, tpinfo.Page); // add the page in the same position it had
                    else
                        parent.TabPages.Add(tpinfo.Page);
                    hiddenPages.Remove(key);
                }
            }
        }

        public static void SetInvisible(this TabPage page)
        {
            if (IsVisible(page))
            {
                TabControl tabCtrl = (TabControl)page.Parent;
                TabPageData tpinfo;
                tpinfo = new TabPageData(tabCtrl.TabPages.IndexOf(page), tabCtrl, page);
                tabCtrl.TabPages.Remove(page);
                hiddenPages.Add(TabPageData.GetKey(tabCtrl, page), tpinfo);
            }
        }

        public static bool IsVisible(this TabPage page)
        {
            return page != null && page.Parent != null; // when Parent is null the tab page does not belong to any container
        }

        public static void CleanUpHiddenPages(this TabPage page)
        {
            foreach (TabPageData info in hiddenPages.Values)
            {
                if (info.Parent != null && info.Parent.Equals((TabControl)page.Parent))
                    info.Page.Dispose();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Works a treat - thanks very much. You might want to file a bug report since Stackoverflow is mangling the start and end of your code.

Comment: Oh, how can I also hide the arrows to the user when there are too many tabs?

Answer (score 6):

I prefer to make the flat style appearance:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25192153/5660876

```
    tabControl1.Appearance = TabAppearance.FlatButtons;
    tabControl1.ItemSize = new Size(0, 1);
    tabControl1.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
```

But there is a pixel that is shown at every tabPage, so if you delete all the text of every tabpage, then the tabs become invisible perfectly at run-time.

```
    foreach (TabPage tab in tabControl1.TabPages)
    {
        tab.Text = "";
    }
```

After that i use a treeview, to change through the tabpages... clicking on the nodes.

Comment: This is the the most elegant solution. 

At first, I thought it wouldnt get around the user tabbing (on keyboard) to the TabControl then using up, down, left and right arrow keys to navigate to a tab even if it was hidden from view. 
However ive tested it, and can confirm this solution prevents users from working around it using tab key and arrow keys. you can programatically switch between the tabs using this: 

TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabPage1

Comment: oh, also have to set TabStop=false

Answer (score 4):

A different approach would be to have two tab controls, one visible, and one not.  You can move the tabs from one to the other like this (vb.net):

```
If Me.chkShowTab1.Checked = True Then
    Me.tabsShown.TabPages.Add(Me.tabsHidden.TabPages("Tab1"))
    Me.tabsHidden.TabPages.RemoveByKey("Tab1")
Else
    Me.tabsHidden.TabPages.Add(Me.tabsShown.TabPages("Tab1"))
    Me.tabsShown.TabPages.RemoveByKey("Tab1")
End If
```

If the tab order is important, change the .Add method on tabsShown to .Insert and specify the ordinal position.  One way to do that is to call a routine that returns the desired ordinal position.

Comment: In my case RemoveByKey works while Remove doesn't work. Only thing that can maybe explain it, is that I tried to removed nested TabPages

Answer (score 2):

you can always hide or show the tabpage.

```
'in VB
myTabControl.TabPages(9).Hide() 'to hide the tabpage that has index 9
myTabControl.TabPages(9).Show() 'to show the tabpage that has index 9
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding and removing tab may be a bit less effective
May be this will help

**To hide/show tab page => let tabPage1 of tabControl1**

```
tapPage1.Parent = null;            //to hide tabPage1 from tabControl1
tabPage1.Parent = tabControl1;     //to show the tabPage1 in tabControl1
```

Answer (score 1):

I have my sample code working but want to make it somewhat more better refrencing the tab from list:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim State1 As Integer = 1
    Dim AllTabs As List(Of TabPage) = New List(Of TabPage)

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Check1(State1)
        State1 = CInt(IIf(State1 = 1, 0, 1))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        AllTabs.Add(TabControl1.TabPages("TabPage1"))
        AllTabs.Add(TabControl1.TabPages("TabPage2"))
    End Sub

    Sub Check1(ByVal No As Integer)
        If TabControl1.TabPages.ContainsKey("TabPage1") Then
            TabControl1.TabPages.Remove(TabControl1.TabPages("TabPage1"))
        End If
        If TabControl1.TabPages.ContainsKey("TabPage2") Then
            TabControl1.TabPages.Remove(TabControl1.TabPages("TabPage2"))
        End If
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add(AllTabs(No))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static Action<Func<TabPage, bool>> GetTabHider(this TabControl container) {
        if (container == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("container");

        var orderedCache = new List<TabPage>();
        var orderedEnumerator = container.TabPages.GetEnumerator();
        while (orderedEnumerator.MoveNext()) {
            var current = orderedEnumerator.Current as TabPage;
            if (current != null) {
                orderedCache.Add(current);
            }
        }

        return (Func<TabPage, bool> where) => {
            if (where == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("where");

            container.TabPages.Clear();
            foreach (TabPage page in orderedCache) {
                if (where(page)) {
                    container.TabPages.Add(page);
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Used like this:

```
    var showOnly = this.TabContainer1.GetTabHider();
    showOnly((tab) => tab.Text != "tabPage1");
```

Original ordering is retained by retaining a reference to the anonymous function instance.

Answer (score 1):

Someone merged the C# answer into this one so I have to post my answer here. I didn't love the other solutions so I made a helper class that will make it easier to hide / show your tabs while retaining the order of tabs.

```
/// <summary>
/// Memorizes the order of tabs upon creation to make hiding / showing tabs more
/// straightforward. Instead of interacting with the TabCollection, use this class
/// instead.
/// </summary>
public class TabPageHelper
{
    private List<TabPage> _allTabs;
    private TabControl.TabPageCollection _tabCollection;
    public Dictionary<string, int> TabOrder { get; private set; }

    public TabPageHelper( TabControl.TabPageCollection tabCollection )
    {
        _allTabs = new List<TabPage>();
        TabOrder = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach ( TabPage tab in tabCollection )
        {
            _allTabs.Add( tab );
        }
        _tabCollection = tabCollection;
        foreach ( int index in Enumerable.Range( 0, tabCollection.Count ) )
        {
            var tab = tabCollection[index];
            TabOrder[tab.Name] = index;
        }
    }

    public void ShowTabPage( string tabText )
    {
        TabPage page = _allTabs
            .Where( t => string.Equals( t.Text, tabText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase ) )
            .First();
        int tabPageOrder = TabOrder[page.Name];
        if ( !_tabCollection.Contains( page ) )
        {
            _tabCollection.Insert( tabPageOrder, page );
        }
    }

    public void HideTabPage( string tabText )
    {
        TabPage page = _allTabs
            .Where( t => string.Equals( t.Text, tabText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase ) )
            .First();
        int tabPageOrder = TabOrder[page.Name];
        if ( _tabCollection.Contains( page ) )
        {
            _tabCollection.Remove( page );
        }
    }
}
```

To use the class, instantiate it in your form load method after initializing your components by passing in the tab control's TabPages property.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _tabHelper = new TabPageHelper( tabControl1.TabPages );
}
```

All of your tab pages should exist on application load (ie: in the Design view) because the class will remember the order of the tab pages when hiding / showing. You can hide or show them selectively throughout your application like this:

```
_tabHelper.HideTabPage("Settings");
_tabHelper.ShowTabPage("Schedule");
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks easier for me to clear all TabPages add add those wished:

```
PropertyTabControl.TabPages.Clear();
        PropertyTabControl.TabPages.Add(AspectTabPage);
        PropertyTabControl.TabPages.Add(WerkstattTabPage);
```

or

```
PropertyTabControl.TabPages.Clear();
        PropertyTabControl.TabPages.Add(TerminTabPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the same approach of saving the hidden TabPages in a private list, but the problem is that when I want to show the TabPage again, they doesn't appears in the original position (order). So, finally, I wrote a class in VB to add the TabControl with two methods: HideTabPageByName and ShowTabPageByName. You can just call the methods passing the name (not the TabPage instance).

```
Public Class CS_Control_TabControl
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.TabControl

    Private mTabPagesHidden As New Dictionary(Of String, System.Windows.Forms.TabPage)
    Private mTabPagesOrder As List(Of String)

    Public Sub HideTabPageByName(ByVal TabPageName As String)
        If mTabPagesOrder Is Nothing Then
            ' The first time the Hide method is called, save the original order of the TabPages
            mTabPagesOrder = New List(Of String)
            For Each TabPageCurrent As TabPage In Me.TabPages
                mTabPagesOrder.Add(TabPageCurrent.Name)
            Next
        End If

        If Me.TabPages.ContainsKey(TabPageName) Then
            Dim TabPageToHide As TabPage

            ' Get the TabPage object
            TabPageToHide = TabPages(TabPageName)
            ' Add the TabPage to the internal List
            mTabPagesHidden.Add(TabPageName, TabPageToHide)
            ' Remove the TabPage from the TabPages collection of the TabControl
            Me.TabPages.Remove(TabPageToHide)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub ShowTabPageByName(ByVal TabPageName As String)
        If mTabPagesHidden.ContainsKey(TabPageName) Then
            Dim TabPageToShow As TabPage

            ' Get the TabPage object
            TabPageToShow = mTabPagesHidden(TabPageName)
            ' Add the TabPage to the TabPages collection of the TabControl
            Me.TabPages.Insert(GetTabPageInsertionPoint(TabPageName), TabPageToShow)
            ' Remove the TabPage from the internal List
            mTabPagesHidden.Remove(TabPageName)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function GetTabPageInsertionPoint(ByVal TabPageName As String) As Integer
        Dim TabPageIndex As Integer
        Dim TabPageCurrent As TabPage
        Dim TabNameIndex As Integer
        Dim TabNameCurrent As String

        For TabPageIndex = 0 To Me.TabPages.Count - 1
            TabPageCurrent = Me.TabPages(TabPageIndex)
            For TabNameIndex = TabPageIndex To mTabPagesOrder.Count - 1
                TabNameCurrent = mTabPagesOrder(TabNameIndex)
                If TabNameCurrent = TabPageCurrent.Name Then
                    Exit For
                End If
                If TabNameCurrent = TabPageName Then
                    Return TabPageIndex
                End If
            Next
        Next
        Return TabPageIndex
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        mTabPagesHidden = Nothing
        mTabPagesOrder = Nothing
        MyBase.Finalize()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Public Shared HiddenTabs As New List(Of TabPage)()
Public Shared Visibletabs As New List(Of TabPage)()
Public Shared Function ShowTab(tab_ As TabPage, show_tab As Boolean)
    Select Case show_tab
        Case True
            If Visibletabs.Contains(tab_) = False Then Visibletabs.Add(tab_)
            If HiddenTabs.Contains(tab_) = True Then HiddenTabs.Remove(tab_)
        Case False
            If HiddenTabs.Contains(tab_) = False Then HiddenTabs.Add(tab_)
            If Visibletabs.Contains(tab_) = True Then Visibletabs.Remove(tab_)
    End Select
    For Each r In HiddenTabs
        Try
            Dim TC As TabControl = r.Parent
            If TC.Contains(r) = True Then TC.TabPages.Remove(r)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    Next
    For Each a In Visibletabs
        Try
            Dim TC As TabControl = a.Parent
            If TC.Contains(a) = False Then TC.TabPages.Add(a)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: You should add some comments detail what is happening in the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

And building upon the answer by Emile (and Slugster), I found it a bit easier to extend the TabControl (instead of the TabPages). In this way I can set pages invisible or visible with a single call, and also not have to worry about the null parent references for the invisible pages.

Example call:
  MyTabControl.SetTabVisibilityExt( "tabTests", isDeveloper);

```
public static class WinFormExtensions
{
    public static TabPage FindTabByNameExt( this TabControl tc, string tabName)
    {
        foreach (TabPage tab in tc.TabPages)
            if (tab.Name == tabName)
                return tab;

        return null;
    }

    private struct TabPageData
    {
        internal int Index;
        internal TabControl Parent;
        internal TabPage Page;

        internal TabPageData(int index, TabControl parent, TabPage page)
        {
            Index = index;
            Parent = parent;
            Page = page;
        }

        internal static string GetKey(TabControl tc, TabPage tabPage)
        {
            string key = "";
            if (tc == null || tabPage == null)
                return key;

            key = $"{tc.Name}:{tabPage.Name}";
            return key;
        }
        internal static string GetKey(TabControl tc, string tabName)
        {
            string key = "";
            if (tc == null)
                return key;

            key = $"{tc.Name}:{tabName}";
            return key;
        }
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, TabPageData> hiddenPages = new Dictionary<string, TabPageData>();

    public static void SetTabVisibleExt(this TabControl tc, string tabName)
    {
        if (tc == null || tc.IsDisposed)
            return;

        if (tc.IsTabVisibleExt(tabName))
            return;

        string key = TabPageData.GetKey(tc, tabName);
        if (hiddenPages.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            TabPageData tpinfo = hiddenPages[key];
            if (tpinfo.Index < tc.TabPages.Count)
                tc.TabPages.Insert(tpinfo.Index, tpinfo.Page); // add the page in the same position it had
            else
                tc.TabPages.Add(tpinfo.Page);

            hiddenPages.Remove(key);
            return;
        }
        else
            throw new ApplicationException($"TabControl={tc.Name} does not have Invisible TabPage={tabName}");
    }

    public static void SetTabInvisibleExt(this TabControl tc, string tabName)
    {
        if (tc == null || tc.IsDisposed)
            return;

        if (IsTabInvisibleExt(tc, tabName))
            return;

        TabPage page = tc.FindTabByNameExt(tabName);
        if (page != null)
        {
            string key = TabPageData.GetKey(tc, page);
            TabPageData tpInfo = new TabPageData(tc.TabPages.IndexOf(page), tc, page);
            tc.TabPages.Remove(page);
            hiddenPages.Add(key, tpInfo);
            return;
        }
        else // Could not find the tab, and it isn't already invisible.
            throw new ApplicationException($"TabControl={tc.Name} could not locate TabPage={tabName}");
    }

    // A convenience method to combine the SetTabInvisible and SetTabInvisible.
    public static void SetTabVisibilityExt(this TabControl tc, string tabName, bool? isVisible)
    {
        if (isVisible == null)
            return;

        if (isVisible.Value)
            tc.SetTabVisibleExt(tabName);
        else
            tc.SetTabInvisibleExt(tabName);
    }

    public static bool IsTabVisibleExt(this TabControl tc, string tabName)
    {
        TabPage page = tc.FindTabByNameExt(tabName);
        return page != null;
    }

    public static bool IsTabInvisibleExt(this TabControl tc, string tabName)
    {
        string key = TabPageData.GetKey(tc, tabName);
        return hiddenPages.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public static void CleanUpHiddenPagesExt(this TabControl tc)
    {
        foreach (TabPageData info in hiddenPages.Values)
        {
            if (info.Parent != null && info.Parent.Equals((TabControl)tc))
                info.Page.Dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to use the `Tag` element of the `TabPage`, you can use this extension methods

```
    public static void HideByRemoval(this TabPage tp)
    {
        TabControl tc = tp.Parent as TabControl;

        if (tc != null && tc.TabPages.Contains(tp))
        {
            // Store TabControl and Index
            tp.Tag = new Tuple<TabControl, Int32>(tc, tc.TabPages.IndexOf(tp));
            tc.TabPages.Remove(tp);
        }
    }

    public static void ShowByInsertion(this TabPage tp)
    {
        Tuple<TabControl, Int32> tagObj = tp.Tag as Tuple<TabControl, Int32>;

        if (tagObj?.Item1 != null)
        {
            // Restore TabControl and Index
            tagObj.Item1.TabPages.Insert(tagObj.Item2, tp);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to code a solution in software... Thanks for posting answers. Just wanted to update this with another version. A TabPage array is used to shadow the Tab Control. During the Load event, the TabPages in the TabControl are copied to the shadow array. Later, this shadow array is used as the source to copy the TabPages into the TabControl...and in the desired presentation order.

```
    Private tabControl1tabPageShadow() As TabPage = Nothing

    Private Sub Form2_DailyReportPackageViewer_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        LoadTabPageShadow()
    End Sub


    Private Sub LoadTabPageShadow()
        ReDim tabControl1tabPageShadow(TabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1)
        For Each tabPage In TabControl1.TabPages
            tabControl1tabPageShadow(tabPage.TabIndex) = tabPage
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub ViewAllReports(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
        TabControl1.TabPages.Clear()
        For Each tabPage In tabControl1tabPageShadow
            TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage)
        Next
    End Sub


    Private Sub ViewOperationsReports(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click
        TabControl1.TabPages.Clear()

        For tabCount As Integer = 0 To 9
            For Each tabPage In tabControl1tabPageShadow
                Select Case tabPage.Text
                    Case "Overview"
                        If tabCount = 0 Then TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage)
                    Case "Production Days Under 110%"
                        If tabCount = 1 Then TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage)
                    Case "Screening Status"
                        If tabCount = 2 Then TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage)
                    Case "Rework Status"
                        If tabCount = 3 Then TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage)
                    Case "Secondary by Machine"
                        If tabCount = 4 Then TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage)
                    Case "Secondary Set Ups"
                        If tabCount = 5 Then TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage)
                    Case "Secondary Run Times"
                        If tabCount = 6 Then TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage)
                    Case "Primary Set Ups"
                        If tabCount = 7 Then TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage)
                    Case "Variance"
                        If tabCount = 8 Then TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage)
                    Case "Schedule Changes"
                        If tabCount = 9 Then TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage)
                End Select
            Next
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Solutions provided by Antony and Suroj are the simplest one.
In Antony's solution, that if condition is must before adding the tabpage. Adding the same tabpage again will actually add the second tabpage and remove controls on both the tabpages.
I used following code in my app.

```
   'Hide all the tabpages except Navigator during app startup.
        For Each itemTab As TabPage In TabControl1.TabPages
            If itemTab.Text <> "Navigator" Then
                TabControl1.TabPages.Remove(itemTab)
            End If
        Next 
    
    'Show the tab on button click
        If Not TabControl1.Controls.Contains(TabDataSource) Then
                TabControl1.TabPages.Add(TabDataSource)
            End If
            TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabDataSource
```

Answer (score -1):

Always codes should be simple and easy to perform tasks for fast performance and for good reliability.

To add a page to a TabControl, the following code is enough.

*If Tabcontrol1.Controls.Contains(TabPage1) Then

else
Tabcontrol1.Controls.Add(TabPage1)
End If*

To remove a page from a TabControl, the following code is enough.

*If Tabcontrol1.Controls.Contains(TabPage1) Then
Tabcontrol1.Controls.Remove(TabPage1)
End If*

I wish to thank Stackoverflow.com for providing sincere help to programmers.

Answer (score -1):

```
TabPanel1.Visible = true; // Show Tabpage 1
TabPanel1.Visible = false; //Hide Tabpage 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: This doesn't work, btw. The `Visible` property does nothing.

Answer (score -1):

First copy the tab into a variable then use insert to bring it back.

```
TabPage tpresult = tabControl1.TabPages[0];
tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(0);
tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(0, tpresult);
```

Answer (score -3):

You Can Use the Following

```
tabcontainer.tabs(1).visible=true
```

1 is tabindex