# Show/hide Tabs in Windowsforms TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to hide TabPage from TabControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552579/how-to-hide-tabpage-from-tabcontrol)
>   [Hiding and Showing TabPages in tabControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365025/hiding-and-showing-tabpages-in-tabcontrol)

I have a Tabcontrol in Windows forms application.It has 5 tabs and at form load i want to show only two tabs

Is there a way to to hide all other tabs

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

go to : http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Show_and_Hide_tab_pages_in_Windows_Forms.aspx

or

also you can use `tabPage.Visible` property

Comment: tabpage.Visible property hides all the tabs,but i want to show few tabs and hide other tabs

Comment: use index to hide TabPage tabControl1.TabPages[index].Visible=false;