# Programmatically hide/remove tabpages in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have 10 tabpages on my form. Based on an input in a textbox, I want to programmatically remove number of tab pages, i.e. if textbox input is 3 then only first 3 tabpages should be visible and tabpages 4 to 10 must be removed or should not be visible. 
I tried following without any success,

```
For i = 0 To 9
Form1.TabControl1.TabPages.Remove(Form4.TabControl1.TabPages((val(textbox1.text)) + i))
Next
```

(No exceptions or errors are generated for above statements)

What is wrong with these statements?

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365025/hiding-and-showing-tabpages-in-tabcontrol

Comment: Tab pages do not have a visible property, the visible property belongs to the tab control not the pages, so the last answer is wrong. It seems that remove is the only way you can do to hide the tab page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check this.

```
    For i As Integer = TextBox1.Text + 1 To 9

        Form1.TabControl1.TabPages.Remove(Form4.TabControl1.TabPages(TextBox1.Text + 1))

    Next
```

or

```
    For index As Integer = 9 To TextBox1.Text + 1 Step -1

        Me.TabControl1.TabPages.Remove(Me.TabControl1.TabPages(index))
    Next
```

Comment: Never use your Input unfiltered.

Answer (score 2):

Never use your Input unfiltered.
Put the Textbix1.Text Input in a integer.tryparse construct.
Also, activate Option strict for better code quality.

For your Problem:

```
Dim MaxVisible as Integer
Dim Sucess as Boolean
Sucess=Integer.Tryparse(textbox1.text, MaxVisible)
If Sucess=True

For index As Integer = 9 To MaxVisible  + 1 Step -1
 Me.TabControl1.TabPages(Index).visible=false
End If
```

That should make the unwanted tabcontrols invisible.
I dont know if Tabpages(index) works, maybe you must youse getitems instead - I have no Winforms Project at hand to test it.
More Information on TabControl: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is another approach that works well to make up for the lack of a visibility property.

On the tab page itself, set the parent property to Nothing to hide it.
when you want to show the tab page, set the tabpage.parent to the tab control.