# Hiding TabPage from TabControl in Winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a TabControl in Winform s application,
I have to disable the second tab,  clicking it would be enabled only after some action on my first page.
I have achieved this by disabling tab by code

```
tabControl1.TabPages[1].Enabled = false;
```

But I want that tab to be hidden or clicking the tab itself should be disabled.

Comment: Add the 2nd tabpage only after you've done the actions on the first page. As discussed in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552579/how-to-hide-tabpage-from-tabcontrol).

Comment: By wrinting event for  tab2, i am able to disable the second tab i.e 
private void Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
        {
           if (e.TabPage == tabControl1.TabPages[1])
           {
               e.Cancel = true;
          }
But now after disabling it through event, how should i enable tab2 click by button click on tab1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hiding and Showing TabPages in tabControl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365025/hiding-and-showing-tabpages-in-tabcontrol)

Comment: @Hans: Yes, a duplicate for hide&show but not for disallowing selection. And since disappearing TabPages usually are a bad UI design I guess I'd prefer catching the Selecting event..

Comment: Hmya, I just hand them the bullets, aiming the gun at the left foot is up to them.  A hidden tabpage can't be selected, problem solved.  The Selecting event isn't exactly ideal either, it can't work when there's only one tabpage :)

Comment: Ha, first you hand out bullets and then you scare them, you sure are innocent today ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This. It will hide and show the TabPages without a Control lost.

**Hide TabPage and Remove the Header:**

```
this.tabPage1.Hide();
this.tabPage3.Hide();
this.tabPage5.Hide();
tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage1);
tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage3);
tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage5);
```

**Show TabPage and Visible the Header:**

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(0,tabPage1);
tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(2, tabPage3);
tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(4, tabPage5);
this.tabPage1.Show();
this.tabPage3.Show();
this.tabPage5.Show();
tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage1;
```

Comment: It is Doing task adding second tab but if i click on tab page2 it is adding more tabs automatically in the tabcontrol and on n click n tabs are getting added.

Comment: You need to handle this programmatically. either add once or if Tab Page already exists ignore. I am using this for user based. Show and hide tab according to user rights.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have asked two questions:

- How to hide a `TabPage`
- How to make it non-selectable

You can't really hide a `TabPage`; the closest and simplest solution is to remove it from the orginal `Tab` control and add it to a hidden helper `Tab` control:

```
tabPage3.Parent = helperTab;
```

To make it non-selectable, you code the `Selecting` event of the `Tab` control. You need to set a flag, maybe in the `Tag` of the page, and then you can prevent a page where the flag is set from being selected:

```
private void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.TabPage.Tag == "X") e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: I made it non selectable by selecting Event but the problem is now after some action on tab1eg: on button click, i want to enable clicking and enable tab2.Which i did by 
tabControl1.TabPages[1].Enabled = true;
So how to navigate to tab2 which is non clickable by selecting event fired?

Comment: You set  Tag to a flag, here "X" make it unselectable or clear it to make it selectable again: `someTabPage.Tag = "";`