# Disable individual TabPages in a TabControl?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a tabControl in my vb.net application - that has 3 tabs. Upon a click on the first tab I'm trying to do something so that user will not be able to get out of that tab - which seems to be a lot more difficult that I anticipated. I'm simply trying to disable the TAB itself - so that they are unable to leave the current tab - the TABPAGE does not have to be disabled since they are not supposed to be able to get out of the current one...

i'm trying something along the way of....

```
tabControl1.tabPage(1).enabled=false
```

and

```
tabcontrol1.tabpage1.enabled=false
```

and even trying to hide it

```
tabcontrol1.tabpage(1).visible=false
```

And nothing seems to work.........!

i've even tried

```
tabPage1.hide()
```

But doesn't do anything

EDIT:

I found this code - will I have to do something with this in order to disable the actual TAB - Not TAB PAGE - I don't want user leaving the tab they've on when they click a specific button...

```
   Private Sub TabControl1_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.DrawItem

    Dim g As Graphics
    Dim sText As String
    Dim iX As Integer
    Dim iY As Integer
    Dim sizeText As SizeF
    Dim ctlTab As TabControl
    ctlTab = CType(sender, TabControl)
    g = e.Graphics

    sText = ctlTab.TabPages(e.Index).Text

    sizeText = g.MeasureString(sText, ctlTab.Font)

    iX = e.Bounds.Left + 6

    iY = e.Bounds.Top + (e.Bounds.Height - sizeText.Height) / 2

    g.DrawString(sText, ctlTab.Font, Brushes.Black, iX, iY)

End Sub
```

Found this here...http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/125792-how-to-make-vertical-tabs/

Comment: I recommend using `Option Explicit On` because the lowercase letters after the dots look suspicious. I think it's something like `tabControl1.TabPages(1).Enabled=False`

Comment: @slai i retyped code here from my application and didn't copy/paste

Comment: Won't say it is the right way, but I just force them to whatever tab I want them to be on with `.SelectedTab` property.

Comment: @slai if you look at my Q - it shows the same exact code and I also explain that it doesn't work

Comment: Will i have to create my own tabs with Owner Fixed?

Comment: I didn't see the `s` in the ones that you tried, but I tried them too and none of them worked. It's mentioned in the [`TabPage` Remarks section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabpage#Anchor_7) : "Additionally, the Hide method of the TabPage will not hide the tab. To hide the tab, you must remove the TabPage control from the TabControl.TabPages collection." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365025/hiding-and-showing-tabpages-in-tabcontrol

Comment: You just need to implement an event handler for the TabControl's Selecting event.  Set e.Cancel = True to stop it.  Making it obvious to the user that he can't change the tab so he won't wildly bang at the other tabs in frustration is up to you.

Comment: @HansPassant - this works great - that's all I really needed. Please post as answer and I will gladly accept it!

Comment: Rather best if you post it yourself so it matches your question well.  Just show what code you used, mark the post as the answer to close your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @Hans Passant I did this to resolve this problem....

```
Private Sub TabControl1_Selecting(sender As Object, e As TabControlCancelEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Selecting

        e.cancel=True

End Sub
```

In my case this works perfectly........

Answer (score 1):

They hide `Enabled` in the property window, but it does partially work.  It wont disable the `TabPage` but as a container control, it does disable all the child controls.  The "trick" then becomes how to convey to the user that this or that tab is available: for that, use the image properties:

```
TabControl1.TabPages(1).Enabled = False
TabControl1.TabPages(1).ImageIndex = 1
```

Result:

[image]

You can embellish to make it clear, for instance a label with "Step 1 must be completed first".  You can *still* intervene to stop the tab change with the `SelectedIndexChanged` event but since they cannot interact with any control, there is no real need.

You can also use the Image part with the `SelectedIndexChanged` event trap, as a means to tell them it is not available.

---

There is yet another way but the other alteratives are simpler.  This can work ok for a Wizard scenario with a "Next >>" type button

- Create a List(of TabPage)
- Store pages 1-N in it
- Remove Pages 1-N from the TabControl (leaving TabPage(0))
- When they hit 'Next`, add the next page back to the control

Example:

```
Select Case TabControl1.TabPages.Count
    Case 1
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add(Pgs(0))
    Case 2
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add(Pgs(1))
    ...
End Select
```

If there is a "New Foo" button to wizard thru the steps for a new Foo, just remove pages 1-N again.   I am not fond of controls coming and going visibility wise, but it can useful when `Step Two` can vary depending on a value in Step 1 (ie either of TabPage 2, 3 *or* 4 can be used for Step 2 depending...).