# Pageview Strip Mode Auto arrange

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have 4 tabs in a windows form PageView Strip mode like Tab1, Tab2, Tab3, Tab4.

Where Tab2 and Tab3 tabs visibility is false that's why empty space found in continuity of 4 tabs.
how can i set property to auto arrange tabs on page load in c# windows form.

By Default Tabs looks like : Tab1   Tab2  Tab3  Tab4

```
    private void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Tab2.Item.Visibility = ElementVisibility.Hidden;
        this.Tab3.Item.Visibility = ElementVisibility.Hidden;
    }
```

After Form Load,
Tabs Looks Like: Tab1 Space Space Tab4         // Big Space between Tab1 and Tab4

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Tab3.Item.Visibility = ElementVisibility.Visible;
    }
```

I want Tab1 Tab4 like this

Comment: Can you please share some code and screenshot of what's going on? Also please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365025/hiding-and-showing-tabpages-in-tabcontrol).

Comment: What's a PageView Strip?  Document your question properly for your audience.

Comment: private void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    this.Tab2.Item.Visibility = ElementVisibility.Hidden;
    this.Tab3.Item.Visibility = ElementVisibility.Hidden;
 }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    this.Tab3.Item.Visibility = ElementVisibility.Visible;
 }

Comment: PageView Strip Mode is just like the formate of browser window... @LarsTech