# c# Hide tabpages in foreach loop

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

I want to hide all pages in a tab control (except 1), but my obvious guess does not work and I can't find anything else.

I try:

```
foreach (TabPage page in myTabControl.TabPages)
    {
        ...
        page.PageVisible = false;    //Compile error here
    }
```

> 'System.Windows.Forms.TabPage' does not contain a definition for
>   'PageVisible' and no extension method 'PageVisible' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TabPage' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You have to remove it from the tab pages collection, Tab pages don't have a visibility property as you found out.

Comment: This answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552579/how-to-hide-tabpage-from-tabcontrol

Comment: Read the [documentaion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6e1ah1k(v=vs.110).aspx) for `TabPage.Visible`.  It states _"To hide a tab in a TabControl, you must remove it from the control's TabPages collection."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the page to hide it and re-add it to make it visible once more. Please see [How to hide TabPage from TabControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552579/how-to-hide-tabpage-from-tabcontrol)